# Mass producing my electronics/raspberry-pi idea - What are the steps?

Tags: raspberry-pi, component-selection, prototyping, manufacturing, production

Could somebody tell me what the rough steps would look like? I think I have a good idea. I have put things into practice, and it's working and so on, but it's very ugly.

I guess, first I would have to build a prototype which looks much more like the final product and is not as ugly and so on. But what are the steps exactly, how do I best build a prototype and then move to mass production?

PS: 'Mass production' might be a bit misleading here: I just want to have 500 pieces at first. I just have no idea where to start and how the process looks like.

Comment: Similar questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64293/how-to-mass-produce-a-electronic-system-assembled-by-me?rq=1 , https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104786/electronics-protyping-and-manufacture?rq=1

Comment: [Sparkfun may be able to help](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-sell-your-widget-on-sparkfun) and has a pretty good guide on how to get started.

Answer (score 4):

Just a list of the main steps I went through:

- Product concept.
- Features selection and limitation.
- Component selection, mainly CPU and big peripherals.
- Schematic entry prototype.
- PCB design prototype.
- Writing, testing & debug real-time embedded code.
- Writing, testing & debug development GUI.
- Assembly prototype.
- Re-design schematic final product.
- PCB design final product.
- Assembly prototypes final products.
- Updating, testing & debug real-time embedded code.
- Updating, testing & debug development GUI.
- Selecting Chinese manufacturer.
- Interfacing with Chinese manufacturer.
- Preparing manufacturing files (e.g. Pick and place coordinates).
- Schematic entry Test-jig.
- PCB design Test-jig.
- Writing, testing & debug Test-jig self test code.
- Writing self-test failure analysis manual.
- Writing, testing & debug Manufacturing self-test GUI.
- Arranging for EU EMC conformity testing.
- Arranging for EU ROHS certificate.
- Negotiating for EU WEEE directive.
- Applying for Registered Trademark.
- Arranging EU/UK import registration.
- Arranging packaging.
- Mechanical outfitting Test-jig.
- Writing manual.
- Writing, testing & debug Drivers for C.
- Writing, testing & debug Drivers for Python.
- Making You-tube instructions & advertise movies.
- Registering and and setting up webpage
- Adding & testing last minute extra features.
- Programming and shipping first 1250 products.

And then you have to set aside plenty of time for customer questions, updates, complaints, returns etc. for the next four years.

Comment: hm, depending on what you build, you might need to add patent research, negotiation, avoidance to that list; or, even, writing, applying for and paying for a patent.

Comment: Also, I'm curious: What *is* the product you developed?

Comment: Not in my case. I may be clever but not **that** clever. Biggest worry was that the product would be just successful enough that the far east market would copy it before I had my return of investment and all my money an effort would be lost. (Can't tell you what it was. Would be advertising. Still ongoing, I am now in the end phase of the sales curve.)

Comment: (well, having worked with a few people trying to bring their patents to buyers/licensees: you don't *have* to be very smart to be holding a patent; neither does the patent have to be very smart)

Comment: if you plan to buy RPis, add hardware and sell the result make sure you can actually buy the model in volume (pi-zeros for example don't seem to be buyable in 100s or 1000s)